# Black space and incorrect lighting when capturing to Composure

Tags: c++, lighting, unreal, unreal-5, post-processing

I'm setting up a Virtual Production project and capturing from a camera to a Composure CG_layer. I then output this CG layer to a Render Target that I have assigned to a material on a virtual LED screen. The resulting image is too bright and shows a black bar along the horizon. Regarding the bar, I've tried messing with fog/light settings but haven't been able to find the answer. Also, as you can see in the second and third image, the blue cube's coloring looks quite different from what's in the viewport (almost unlit). I don't have these problems when using a SceneCapture2D actor/component to send to a Render Target, but I want to do this with Composure (since I need to combine layers). Any idea what settings I should look at?

[OFF WORLD LIVE reports the same problem and recommends buying their plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UqMhtpbZh0&ab_channel=OFFWORLDLIVE) (of course), but is there no way to fix this natively?

EDIT: I've found you can get rid of the black bar going to the cg layer's SceneCaptureComponent2D and unchecking “Consider Unrendered Opaque Pixel as Fully Translucent”. Still working on figuring out the other lighting discrepancies.

[image: the problem looks like this]

[image: the blue cube lighting is wrong]