# How can I load symbols for Composure?

Tags: unreal, windows, visual-studio, debugging, unreal-5

I'm trying to load symbols so I can use breakpoints in Composure scripts and see how they control the PostProcessing of the SceneCapture2D component (because of [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/206297/black-space-and-incorrect-lighting-when-capturing-to-composure) problem), but breakpoints hit. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, [setting the Composure plugin's LoadingPhase to PreDefault](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/bug-debug-symbols-for-plugin-only-load-if-loadingphase-predefault/538040/7) and even editing the Windows Registry to allow for loading more Debug symbols. But none of this works because I can't find pdb files for Composure.dll, ComposureEditor.dll or ComposureLayersEditor.dll. Are these unavailable? I'd expect them to be in UE_5.1/Engine/Plugins/Compositing/Composure/Binaris/Win64, but there's nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

You must build Unreal from source and specify pdb generation.

This is an option under the Unreal Build Tool C# files for the plugin. This assumes the plugin source is available.

If it is provided compiled only, there are no symbols available, and your quest is without merit.